# Is there an EE plugin that gives greater control over channel permissions?

Tags: module, users, admin, permissions

I have to build a site for a client that requires 9 different content editors admin groups and 3 publisher admin groups. A lot of what I want to do **could** be done by allowing certain groups access to categories rather than closing them off to whole channels.

Does anyone know of a third party plugin that makes admin user permissions more powerful or easier to use? I searched Devot-ee and couldn't find anything.

An example of what I want to do is a news channel:

This website has 5 different categories of news - some editors will only be allowed access to 2 categories, but still need access to the news channel. So as far as I can tell, I'll need to make 2 different news channels to block the users' access to the 3 categories they are not allowed to post to. Obviously I'd rather have one channel and close access to the categories, not the other way round.

Thanks for your help,

Ant

Answer (score 2):

Can you use [Safecracker](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html)? Then there would be no need give the editors access to the CP at all. After logging in they would see the Safecracker form and can add an entry. You could then set the available categories in the form in regard of the user group. If editor1 is part of the editor_group_2 he´ll get access to the news_category1 and news_category_4. 
This would solve the editor issue. Do the publishers also need to have this granular access to the categories?

As a second option [Better Workflow](http://betterworkflow.electricputty.co.uk/) might be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

One more vote for Safecracker. This would allow much more flexibility.

You then might use complex conditionals as well as add-ons like [Member Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/member-categories) and [Entry Access](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-access)

Remember that the restrictions you set in Control Panel still have effect if you use Safecracker, so member's group should still have access to publish to the channel - even you restrict that somehow on actual entry form page.